# SQLAlchemy; prevent automatic selection when ordering

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

With [SQLAlchemy ORM](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) querying with [PostgreSQL(v9.5)](http://www.postgresql.org/); how to prevent the automatic selection when sorting by a column; the sorted column should not be selected.

Hopefully the sample code below makes this more clear.

**Example code**

A table with an integer 'id', an integer 'object_id' and a string 'text':

```
id | object_id | text
---------------------
1  | 1         | house
2  | 2         | tree
3  | 1         | dog
```

The following query should return the distinct `object_id` as its own `id` with the most recent `text`:

```
query = session.query(
    MyTable.object_id.label('id'),
    MyTable.text
).\
    distinct(MyTable.object_id).\
    order_by(MyTable.object_id, MyTable.id.desc())
```

So far so good; but when I compile the query:

```
print(query.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
```

The `mytable.id` and `mytable.object_id` are selected as well, so the column `id` is specified twice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (mytable.object_id) mytable.object_id AS id,
                                               mytable.text,
                                               mytable.object_id,
                                               mytable.id
FROM mytable
ORDER BY mytable.object_id,
         mytable.id DESC
```

Comment: Which version of SQLAlchemy are you using? This was recently fixed I believe, see [here](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3518/consider-rolling-back-refining-automatic)

Comment: Version 1.0.12; Released on February 15, 2016, so I suppose its up-to-date

Comment: I just checked the [issue](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3641/refine-distinct-order_by-add-primary-cols); it is marked as resolved for 1.1, which is not yet released

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. It should work:

```
query = session.query(MyTable.object_id.distinct().label('id'), MyTable.text).order_by(MyTable.object_id, MyTable.id.desc())
```

Comment: `ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Comment: The `sql` compiletr returns `SELECT DISTINCT mytable.object_id AS id, mytable.text 
FROM mytable ORDER BY mytable.object_id, mytable.id DESC
`; and since there is no DISTINCT ON `mytable.id` it can apparently not be sorted by it